# How can I effectively modify a variable based on the string value of a form question?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to modify a variable that gets a specific Sheet by Name based on the response to a form question. That is, if 'Fruit' is the answer to a question, the following script should consider the 'Fruits' Sheet as the targetSheet for script execution.

I've tried using a switch with let to redeclare the targetSheet variable in a for loop.

The result is a SyntaxError stating that targetSheet has already been declared

```
function pickASheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Form');
  var sourceData = s.getDataRange().getValues();
  let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Fruits');

  for (var i = 1; i < sourceData.length; i++) {
    var groceryType = sourceData[i][2]; //Column where value will be 'Fruit' or Vegetable'

    switch (targetSheet) {
      case groceryType == 'Fruit':
        let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Fruits');
        break;
      case groceryType == 'Vegetable':
        let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Vegetables');
        break;
    }
}
}
```

I expect the variable to be redeclared based on the cases, however it seems I am unable to redeclare within the switch.

Comment: What is your expected behavior? What action do you want to perform? I'd suggest removing the "let"s in your switch statement and declare you targetSheet as a variable before the for loop. But it would be more helpful to know what behavior/task you want to accomplish.

Comment: Use `var`?`````````````````​`````````````````